# JS & SAPUI 5 : wait for 2 asynchronous functions WITHOUT setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sapui5

Here is the code I use in SAPUI5 to get data from an odata service :

```
        var sServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/PlanningV0_2/proxy/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPM_OM_WORKMANAGER_SRV";
        var oOdataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceUrl);
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oEmployeeModel = new JSONModel();
        var oOperationModel = new JSONModel();
        var aEmployees = [];
        var aOperations = [];

        //set odata models
        var readEmp = oOdataModel.read("/EmployeeSet",{
            success : function(oData,response){
                oEmployeeModel.setData(oData);
                oView.setModel(oEmployeeModel,"EmployeeModel");
                aEmployees = oEmployeeModel.getData().results;
            },
            error : function(oError){
                console.log(oError);
            }
        });

        var aFilters = [new Filter("PersNo",FilterOperator.NE,"00000000")];
        var readOp = oOdataModel.read("/OrderOperationSet",{
            filters : aFilters,
            success : function(oData,response){
                oOperationModel.setData(oData);
                oView.setModel(oOperationModel,"OperationModel");
                aOperations = oOperationModel.getData().results;
            },
            error : function(oError){
                console.log(oError);
            }
        });
```

After those read functions I want to reuse the arrays aEmployees and aOperations to build a custom model and bind it to my view. The problem is : these functions are asynchrone. If I put a `console.log(aEmployees)` right after the last line, it displays an empty array.

**How can I wait for the end of the two async functions to use the arrays ?**

I looked for something like sleep() or wait() to wait for the end of async functions, but it seems it doesn't exist for JavaScript.

**EDIT : PRECISION** I ask because I prefer to avoid setTimeout, because I don't want to put the treatment code into a callback, I find it awfuly readable, I want to access to 'this' easily if needed, and I don't want to use a hardcoded waiting time.

**EDIT : ANSWER** I used the `attachBatchRequestCompleted`, according to @Qualiture advises, to build the arrays :

```
oOdataModel.attachBatchRequestCompleted(function(){
            var aEmp = oView.getModel("EmployeeModel").getData().results;
            var aOp = oView.getModel("OperationModel").getData().results;
        });
```

It doesn't matter how many requests are bound to the odata model, this event handler will catch them all in the end. Obviously, it is a callback, but I figured out that it is impossible to deal without. The point is that I don't have to hardcode a waiting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ODataModel's `attachRequestCompleted` event handler:

```
yourModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent){
    var oModel = oEvent.getSource();
    //etc
});
```

Do this for both models, and once both events are catched, you can do your magic building your custom model structure

Comment: There is only one ODataModel that is changed twice, the others are JSONModel and don't have this handler. I thought about it but even with the doc I don't understand how the handler will wait for the two read.

Comment: Then use the same handler, and fill the appropriate array with the returned data. Once both arrays contain data, process your custom model

Comment: Actually, it's `attachBatchRequest` for sap.ui.model.odata. **v2** .ODataModel.

Since I bound models to the view, in the handler I call the function `getModel()` and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works! Actually, callbacks are pretty awesome since they allow for asynchronicity and (when using functions properly) actually allows for better readability of your code. On a sidenote, `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.read` does *not* store data into the model, whereas `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.read` does store it. Happy coding! :)